# How to use AJAX / JSON to add details to mySQL database using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, json

Here I'm trying to send two `variables` to my `php` file:

I keep getting errors in my PHP..
`mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli and undefined indexes` for the two `variables`

It's like their not being sent or received correctly.

```
var name = "John";
var address = "UK";

var sendInfo = {
   Name: name,
   Address: address
};

var params = JSON.stringify(sendInfo);
alert(params);

var httpSend = new XMLHttpRequest();
var php = "http://server/~name/folder/insertOffer.php";
httpSend.open("POST", php, true);

httpSend.onreadystatechange = function()
{
   if(httpSend.readyState == 4 && httpSend.status == 200) {

   }
}

httpSend.send(params);
```

PHP file: adding the `variables` to the database

```
<?php

include("mysqlconnect.php");

$name = $_POST['Name']; 
$address = $_POST['Address'];

mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO offerSelected (Id, Url) VALUES ('".$name."','".$address."')");

?>
```

**mysqlconnect.php** equals this:

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pass");

if(!$connection){
die('Could not connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("table", $connection);
?>
```

**UPDATED VERSION**

```
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "pass", "table");
$stmt = $connection->prepare('INSERT INTO offerSelected (Id, Url) VALUES (?, ?)');
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $name, $address);
$stmt->execute();
?>
```

JavaScript

```
var xmlhttp1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
var name = "John";
var address = "UK";
var params = 'Name=' + name + '&Address=' + address;
var php_url = "http://server/~name/folder/insertOffer.php";
xmlhttp1.open('POST', php_url, true);

xmlhttp1.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp1.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if (xmlhttp1.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp1.status == 200) {
       var response1 = xmlhttp1.responseText;
       response1 = JSON.parse(response1);
       alert(response1);
       console.log(response1);
       alert('Check the browser console');
   }
}

xmlhttp1.send(params);
```

My response alert doesn't activate at all.

Comment: Did you try to make a `var_dump($_SERVER, $_POST)` in you PHP file to check what is send by the JS ?

Answer (score 0):

you use mysql_connect, thats wrong for mysqli ;)
look here: [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php)

Comment: please see my updated version, empty rows are being added to the database

Comment: behind "Adress" there is a "=" missing, is there any other output in your console?

Comment: I only can guess, so check that the data gets to your PHP-file, also check if your columns in your database table have the type "varchar"

Comment: Added the most recent update.. the alerts don't activate in the javaScript. I changed the columns in the database from varchar to text no difference.

Comment: Do you get a status of 200 when sending your request, you can see this in the network-tab in your browser console. Else what do you get?

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_connect` in your mysqlconnect.php returns a MySQL link identifier, but not the Mysqli object which needs for `mysqli_query` in your main php file. You should use Mysqli both files.

Comment: Added the most recent update.. the alerts don't activate in the javaScript.

Comment: `if (xmlhttp1.readyState == 0 && xmlhttp1.status == 200)` should be `if (xmlhttp1.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp1.status == 200)`. Look what `readyState` means: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_onreadystatechange.asp

Comment: Apologies, I understand the process of the states, it was a typo here but not in my code. The alerts still don't activate. Any other advice

Answer (score 0):

you have to use  mysqli_connect("myhost","myuser","mypassw","mybd") instead mysql_connect and mysqli_select_db(connection,dbname); instead  of mysql_select_db();

Comment: That has been altered thank, I have updated my question with the most recent code. I'm still not getting the values through